# Adding shadow to textbox onFocus

Tags: jquery, css, shadow

I want to make this sort of Pinterest effect on my registration form - when the user focuses on an input text field or text area, I want this field or area to have a soft shadow around it, like this:

[image]

So I tried the following - I wrote a CSS class

```
.inputShadow{
box-shadow:0 0 10px 5px #900;
}
```

and tried to add it with onFocus="addShadow()", where this was the addShadow() function:

```
function addShadow(){
    $(this).addClass("inputShadow");
}
```

but I didn't get any shadow. Then I tried this:

```
$(function(){
    $("input").onfocus("addClass","inputShadow");
});
```

Also without result. Finally I tried this:

```
$(function(){
    $("input").onfocus("css","box-shadow:0 0 10px 5px #900;");
});
```

but that didn't help me either.

Any ideas how to make it work? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Haven't tested it but this should work:

```
$(function(){
   $("input").on("focus",function(){
       $(this).addClass(".inputShadow");
   });
});
```

Edit: also check browser compatibility, as mentioned in other answer

Comment: Thank you very much! Worked excellent! I added also onBlur to it, to remove the shadow and everything worked just fine! Again, thanks!!

Comment: No problem, check fox32's answer. It's JavaScript-less and if it works it is definitely a better choice.

Comment: Yup, tested it and it worked like a charm! Thank you both very much! :)

Answer (score 3):

No need to use jQuery for this task, you can use css only, too:

```
input:focus {
  /* Your shadow css here */
  -moz-box-shadow:0 0 10px 5px #900;
  -webkit-box-shadow:0 0 10px 5px #900;
  box-shadow:0 0 10px 5px #900;
}
```

But creminsn is right, box-shadow might not work with every browser, you need to add a browser specific prefix.

Comment: That's a great advice! Thank you very much! Tested it now and it worked great! Thank you!!!

Answer (score 1):

what browser are you using as mozilla and chrome browsers have a different css rules.

e.g.

```
.inputShadow {
    -moz-box-shadow:0 0 10px 5px #900;
    -webkit-box-shadow:0 0 10px 5px #900;
    box-shadow:0 0 10px 5px #900;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your input! Yes, I'm aware of these issues, I have theme in my CSS as well, just didn't want to output too much info here. I use latest FF, and I know it supports box-shadow (tried it on other elements), so I just wrote the above code here. Of course I did put the other rules for other browsers. Even for really old IE - `filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Shadow(Strength=10, Direction=0, Color='#900');` :)